# Placing elements in CSS

Tags: css

I am currently making some tests from basic css features. I want to position the menu in the page and I also add a title w/o `<h>`. The menu is stuck to the corner of the page (seems weird). The properties 'top', 'left'... are without effet. It's like if the property top is not taken into account for ?! The choice of the browser is not determining. I put the css in the `<style>`. So graphically the code doesn't achieve the correct display. Any opinion about that ?

```css
#menu ul {
  margin-top: 5cm top: 5cm;
  left: -5cm;
  display: block;
  width: 2cm;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu ul li {
  margin-top: 5cm top: 5cm;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
}

#menu ul li a {
  margin-top: 5cm top: 5cm;
  display: block;
  font-family: "comic sans MS";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

div .blank {
  height: 10cm;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="blank">Ici se trouve la zone titre
</div>
<br/>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lien 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lien 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lien 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lien 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lien 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img />
```

https://www.cjoint.com/c/IJyoxydR3eh

Comment: talking strictly of the `left`, `top` property, these are taken into account only if the `position` is set to `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`. Please clarify the expected output, maybe I can suggest something.

Comment: How do you want your menu to look?

Comment: Note that the `<br>` and `<img>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML and never have.

Comment: @Guilherme, to detail my question. I'd like a div block at the begining of the page, here set at blank of 10cm (it's a lot, but I can try with 2 cm/4 em...). Then the menu with 5 blocks with a green border and hover. The top & margin-top may be redundant / super-additive but it doesn't impact the result (apparently). The unit also... (?).

Comment: @Rob : thanks or this comment. makes sense.

Comment: If you can add a image of what you want, we can help you more easily

Answer (score 0):

You should only be adding `position:absolute;` to the menu element and not all the other children elements.

Take a quick look at the following demo and you will see waht I'm talking about:

```css
#menu ul{
    display: block;
    width: 2cm;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
}

#menu ul li a{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-family: "comic sans MS";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    background-color: gray;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

#menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


img{
    top: 8cm;
    left: 3cm;
    content:url("smiley.jpg");
    width: 10cm;
    height: 6cm;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}

div .blank{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    height: 10cm;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="blank">Ceci est la zone titre
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lien 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lien 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lien 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lien 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lien 5</a></li>     
    </ul>
</div>

<img />
```

Comment: Thanks for the re-structuration of the style. I guess this is more relevant. Do you know why the menu 5 only appears (layout issue) ? Could it be a problem with the compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

So I would like to display a header block with background-color (or image) and the menu anywhere in my page using the coordinates (x,y,w,h). The z-index works fine, as the image shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCE7M.png)